# Intersect faces between 2 objects without join or boolean modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, knife-tool

I'm kind of lost in my research, in a scene I'm trying to modify an object that intersects another object.

Let me explain, so I go with the example I've seen many times with 2 cubes among each other.

[image]

These are 2 different objects; what I want is to add a face where the intersection occurs.

If I try the boolean modifier, it might look like what I want, but the mesh didn't change :/

[image]
[image]

So another solution was to join both objects to then use the intersect knife tool. But then I can't work on each cube independently.

Am I clear on what I want?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe what you want is to "apply" the boolean.  If you don't apply it, the boolean is a live modifier that reacts to to changes in the base objects, so it can't write to the base mesh-- what the base mesh is, depends on those objects.  If you apply it, it is no longer live, but then applied to the mesh for edit mode.  To apply it, look at the dropdown arrow to the right of the modifier name and select "apply".

Comment: Brillant, exactly my need, thanks !